# react-select template issues when selecting one of the data

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

I have a problem when selecting one of the data, then my card elements come extending downward.

Here is the [first following picture](https://ibb.co/4N8BkYH)

and the [second picture](https://ibb.co/qrgqTKf) after select one of the data

this is my select code

```
<div className="col-md-2">
    <h6>Agent Name</h6>
    <Select
        value={{ label: filter_carrier_name }}
        options={optionsCarrier}
        onChange={this.changeHandlerCarrier} />
    {filter_carrier_name_error ? (
        <span style={{ fontSize: 13, color: "red" }}>{filter_carrier_name_error}</span>
    ) : null}
</div>
```

Comment: You mean, when you click on the **search bar**, the search suggestions field pushes the **table field** down?

Comment: it's happen when i direct my pointer to one of the data. if i click search bar its normal.

Comment: there seems to be a conflict with the template that I am using. but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Provide an online demo is preferred.

Comment: If it's a `react-app`, you can create an online demo of your app in **codesandbox.io**, and share the demo here so we can better understand it.

Comment: i've already solve the problem. its from my css that i've been using and resulting in conflict with react-select. I do some modification in my css and its working fine. Thank you for the advice. :)